# Disable JSHint warnings in CodeMirror

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint, codemirror

I thought this would be a trivial question, but I've done a ton of searching and haven't been able to find anything.

I have a CodeMirror div that has linting turned on. I've included JSHint.js, which is working properly; syntax errors and warnings are being displayed in my CodeMirror editor. However, I need to disable a few warnings (most importantly, I want to allow unquoted object keys).

Where can I pass preferences or disable warnings to JSHint so that it only shows the issues that I actually care about?

Or, alternatively, is there a alternative to JSHint that allows more configuration (and is usable with the CodeMirror linting framework)?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set JSHint-specific [options](http://www.jshint.com/docs/) directly in the object you use as the value of CodeMirror's "lint" option.

Comment: An example should be nice.

Answer (score 1):

```js
codemirror.setOption('lint', { options: { bitwise: true }});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the lint property from the CodeMirror config object, to set any valid jshint configuration.

Example:

```js
 const config = {
            lineNumbers: true, 
            lineWrapping: true, 
            mode: 'javascript',
            indentWithTabs: true,
            gutters: ['CodeMirror-lint-markers'], 
            lint: { 'esversion': '8' }, 
            theme: 'monokai'
        };

 var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(document.body, config);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set lint option = false when initializing an instance of the codemirror

```
var editorSettings = CodeMirror.defaults;   
editorSettings.codemirror.lint = false;
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(document.body, editorSettings);
```

In Wordpress 4.9+:

```
var editorSettings = wp.codeEditor.defaultSettings;
editorSettings.codemirror.lint = false;
var editor = wp.codeEditor.initialize( $('#whatever'), editorSettings);
```